# Readmore Js truncates only div container but not text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Readmore Js only collapses the div block and not the text. Pls I need help getting it to truncate text and div container not just div alone. Thanks a lot

[image]
[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="readmore.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w32.css"
</head>
<body>
<div class="w3-container w3-round w3-border w3-grey" style="width: 600px;            margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 300px">
<p class="readmore">London is the most populous city in the United      Kingdom
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants 
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".readmore").readmore({
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try adding `overflow: hidden` to the div?

Comment: Is your <div> tag intentionally unterminated?

Comment: Hello everyone! I inserted 'overflow:hidden' and it worked. Pls how do I set it to truncate after a set number of lines. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I would add some simple css to solve this. The `overflow` property stops the contents from expanding past the size of its parent.

```
.readmore {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/1bb9Lkxb/

Comment: Hello.. it worked fine after inserting that. Pls how do I get it to truncate after a set number of lines. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.readmore {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or if you want to scroll inside the block

```
.readmore {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Adding scroll negates the point of having readmore. Other than that, seems like this is the same answer as mine.

Comment: nevermind, its a low level question, i answered in second sry for the plagia